# S3 treeview using Agile UI

Tags: php, jquery, amazon-s3, treeview

I would like to follow this guide to build a php site with read only S3 Treeview listing. 
[Agile UI Documentation website](http://agile-ui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)

However, it always said class not found for `\atk4\ui\View\Tree()` after I load the package using composer with latest version. It can find `\atk4\ui\View()`. Is this page retired or I need to load different version of atk4\ui?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Agile UI is a pretty new framework, so the documentation has already been updated with more relevant instructions.